# Snowflake unable to bind an object into a query to insert it into a variant column even when using JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, sql, object, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This stored procedure will take an object and insert it into a variant column of a table:

```
try {
  var table_query = "CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE FIELD_NAME_TABLE (field_variant VARIANT)";
  var table_query_stmt_result = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: table_query}).execute();
  var insert_query = "INSERT INTO FIELD_NAME_TABLE SELECT ?";
  var insert_stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: insert_query, binds: [(TABLE_COL_AND_FIELDS)]});
  var result = insert_stmt.execute();
  result.next();
  return result;
  return result['number of rows inserted'];
}
catch(err) {
  return err.message;
}
```

`TABLE_COL_AND_FIELDS` is an object having the following structure:

```
{
   "field1": "val1",
   "field2": "val2"
}
```

When running the script I am getting the following error:

```
"Invalid binds argument[object Object]. Error: Unsupported type for binding argument 2undefined"
```

I added `JSON.parse(TABLE_COL_AND_FIELDS)` and got this error:

> "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

I tried:

`(TABLE_COL_AND_FIELDS).toString()`

And I've got an error of:

```
"SQL compilation error:\nExpression type does not match column data type, expecting VARIANT but got VARCHAR(15) for column FIELD_VARIANT"
```

`FIELD_VARIANT` is the column having type of `VARIANT` in the temporary table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution by adding `parse_json()` to the query text, and `JSON.stringify()` within the `binds` part. The script is as follows:

```
try {
  var table_query = "CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE FIELD_NAME_TABLE (field_variant VARIANT)";
  var table_query_stmt_result = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: table_query}).execute();
  var insert_query = "INSERT INTO FIELD_NAME_TABLE SELECT parse_json(?)";
  var insert_stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: insert_query, binds: [JSON.stringify(TABLE_COL_AND_FIELDS)]});
  var result = insert_stmt.execute();
  result.next();
  return result;
  return result['number of rows inserted'];
}
catch(err) {
  return err.message;
}
```

Comment: How would it work if there are 2 columns in the table, one of them Variant and one Varchar?